# How can I get CUDA to work without messing up my PC?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, blender

I recently had to reinstall Ubuntu completely, and I lost all of my app data.

The reason was because I am an animator and I use Blender. I was trying to get my Nvidia GeForce 8600 GT to work with it. Ubuntu was using Nouveau as the driver, but then I installed the packages for CUDA, rebooted, and the boot up failed. I even tried hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but the screen glitched and ignored half of my keystrokes, making it impossible to enter my password.

I reinstalled Ubuntu and got it the way I want it again, but it's using the same driver as last time (Nouveau). I still want CUDA, but wasn't sure how I could safely get it.

So my question is, how can I safely "test out" or "try out" a boot with the Nvidia drivers? Would it be safer to apply them in the "Software and Updates" application? Is there a way to get CUDA without applying all the other drivers? Or even better, is there a way to render on GPU in Blender without installing a bunch of other drivers?

Sorry, relatively new to graphics drivers. Thanks!

Comment: Your graphics card is mildly ancient (10y) and isn't supported by the latest drivers. You'lll need to limit yourself to the 340.* version. No idea if that's compatible with the CUDA libraries but worth a go. That or drop £75 on a second hand GTX 950.

Comment: @Oli I wondered, as I got that graphics card from a friend who got a better one for his own computer. Seemed to work fine until I put it under a load, but it's still faster than the CPU (a little, anyway).

Comment: Why do you think you need CUDA?

Comment: @CelticWarrior Have you not read the question? I am an animator, and I want my graphics card to work with my animation program, and the animation program can only use CUDA to work with the graphics card. Right now I do CPU renders, but I want to do GPU.

Comment: I see, it's a requirement in Linux indeed. CUDA doesn not work with the open source driver, you need to install the Nvidia proprietary drivers for your card first. Now, if the current CUDA SDK requires newer drivers than the ones that work for your card (very likely), you'll have to upgrade your hardware.

Comment: @CelticWarrior ah, I see.